# Convert JSON objects from textarea to javaScript objects and print into table(strictly JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a text-area(HTML) where i will be entering Json objects manually and i 
   want to convert that into javaScript object and print it into a table. I 
   tried but couldn't figure it out. (strictly javaScript only). For demo 
   purpose i am trying to print it in a paragraph.

```js
 function addJson(){
    var textAreaValue = document.getElementById('jsonTextArea').value;
    var jsObject = JSON.parse(textAreaValue);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsObject.name+"  " 
    +jsObject.city;
    }
    //example json object : { "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
    <textarea   id = "jsonTextArea" placeholder = "JSON Text..."></textarea>
   
    <input type="button" id="addJson"  onclick="addJson()" value="Add">
```

Comment: Do you have any error ?

Comment: @Superdrac when i enter the objects through the textbox, there is no output

Comment: Added snippet, seems working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var addJson = function() {
    var textAreaValue = document.getElementById('jsonTextArea').value;
    var jsObject = JSON.parse(textAreaValue);
    console.log( jsObject );
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsObject.name+"  " +jsObject.city;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea   id = "jsonTextArea" placeholder = "JSON Text..."></textarea>

<input type="button" id="addJson"  onclick="addJson()" value="Add">
```

Comment: I tried inserting the JSON through the text-box and still nothing happening

Comment: @Prag  try the snippet

Comment: Can also confirm that the snippet works as expected [pic](http://i.imgur.com/xs7b99U.png)

Answer (score 0):

The only error I could find was the function wasn't declared correctly.

```js
var addJson = function(){
  var textAreaValue = document.getElementById('jsonTextArea').value;
  var jsObject = JSON.parse(textAreaValue);
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsObject.name+"  " 
  +jsObject.city;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea   id = "jsonTextArea" placeholder = "JSON Text..."></textarea>

<input type="button" id="addJson"  onclick="addJson()" value="Add">
```

If you want an inline script:

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<textarea   id = "jsonTextArea" placeholder = "JSON Text..."></textarea>

<input type="button" id="addJson"  onclick="addJson()" value="Add">
<script>
  var addJson = function(){
    var textAreaValue = document.getElementById('jsonTextArea').value;
    var jsObject = JSON.parse(textAreaValue);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsObject.name+"  " 
    +jsObject.city;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I want the input from text-box , not like what you have given

Comment: Sure, I was just making it more convenient to press the add button to see the result. As it stands, having any user forced to enter valid JSON seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Yeah it worked when i directly added , but when i tried through the text-box, , it didn't happen

Comment: OK, I've removed the automatic filling of the information.  Copy and paste to your hearts content!

Comment: I tried adding { "name":"John", "city":"New York"} into the text-box, but the output is still nil.

Comment: What browser?  This works for me in the latest chrome, FF, and IE 11.

Comment: It is chrome and am tying  using w3schools tryit editor, so it has to work irrespective of browser versions

Comment: I have added the inline code.  You can copy that to the Tryit Editor and see that you can input the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Should work fine once you have your javascript added properly with the word "function" before "addJson(){"